# Shopping Cart Quantity Value Update using AJAX Session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm doing with a WP Site, I've a Shop cart(plugins) and product page where products are listed it has a calss eStore_button.

```
<input class="eStore_button" type="image" alt="Add to Cart" src="http://localhost/met/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/add-to-cart.gif">
```

So I've done a div area on WP Header page where cart quantity will display

```
<td align="center" valign="middle" width="110" class="numberincart"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/shoppingcart" class="start-selling-first"><span id="numberincart"><p><?php echo $_GET['inCart'] ?></p></span></a></td>
```

And I have tried when a user will add a product so very recently it will update on the top of the header so I've wrote below things but not working (the results are not updating on the header, while using firebug I didn't find any bug).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $(".eStore_button").live("click",function(event){
        $.ajax({ url: "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/products?inCart=<?php $_SESSION['inCart']?>",
        }
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Only it is working if I put like this, but not without refresh ...

```
   <td align="center" valign="middle" width="110" class="numberincart"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/shoppingcart" class="start-selling-first"><span id="numberincart"><p><?php echo $_SESSION['inCart'] ?></p></span></a></td>
```

Comment: `not working` is not a descriptive technical explanation for anything... how is anyone supposed to interpret that, especially when AJAX is concerned since problem could be server code related or client side...a demo that replicates problem alsways helps. You can get great hhelp here, but it requires more effort in specifying what issues are. What does work, what errros are being thrown, what have you done to troubleshoot ...etc

Comment: the results are not updating on the header, while using firebug I didn't find any bug

Comment: ok..if using firebug inspect ajax request itself and see what is being sent and returned (if any) and status.

Comment: Just noticed you have no `success` or `done` callback in `$.ajax` to do anything with returned data

Comment: This is what I need   

  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $(".eStore_button").click(function(){
 $("#numberincart").html("<p><?php echo $_SESSION['inCart']?></p>");
 });
 });

but after clicking its appearing only for a second, whats happen to this ?

Comment: need to browser prevent default on link or browser will open url